# Count Function with Linked Table

Tags: sql-server, count

I am attempting to count the number of parts ordered by each of our customers in 2013.
 However the returned results seem to be grouped by order number and not trader.  I am using the following select statement;

```
SELECT orders.traderid, COUNT(orderitems.partid) AS configuredparts
FROM   orders LEFT JOIN orderitems 
ON orders.id = orderitems.orderid AND orders.ordertype = orderitems.ordertype
WHERE        (orderitems.partid LIKE N'P%') AND (YEAR(orders.createddate) = 2013)
GROUP BY orders.traderid, orderitems.partid, orders.ordertype
HAVING        (orders.ordertype = N'SO')
ORDER BY orders.traderid
```

an example of my results are

```
traderid    configured parts
800001           3
800001           3
800001           2
800001           1
A00002           1
A00002           2
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED TO WRITE YOUR TITLE IN ALL CAPS, since it's already bold and big. Filter it through `tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]` to make our eyes stop bleeding.

Answer (score 1):

This answer gives the total number (count) of part ids in table [order items] by trader id in table [orders].

```
trader_id        part_id          total_parts
800001           P001             3
800001           P002             2
A00002           P001             1
```

If table [order items] has a qty column, you should change COUNT(oi.partid) to SUM(oi.qty).

```
SELECT 
  o.traderid as trader_id, 
  oi.partid as part_id,
  COUNT(oi.partid) AS total_parts
FROM   
  orders as o 
LEFT JOIN 
  orderitems as oi
ON 
  o.id = oi.orderid AND 
  o.ordertype = oi.ordertype
WHERE 
  (oi.partid LIKE N'P%') AND 
  (o.createddate >= '20130101') AND
  (o.createddate < '20140101') AND
  (o.ordertype = N'SO')
GROUP BY 
  o.traderid, oi.partid 
ORDER BY 
  o.traderid, oi.partid
```

Last but not least, why does the caption have a **linked table** (server)?

If you are using a linked server you will need to use 4 part notation.

Linked_Server_Name.Database_Name.Schema_Name.Object_Name

Answer (score 0):

give this a go

```
SELECT orders.traderid, COUNT(orderitems.partid) AS configuredparts
FROM   orders LEFT JOIN orderitems AND orders.ordertype = orderitems.ordertype
ON orders.id = orderitems.orderid 
WHERE (orderitems.partid LIKE N'P%') AND (orders.createddate >= '20130101') 
       AND (orders.createddate < '20140101') AND (orders.ordertype = N'SO')
GROUP BY orders.traderid
ORDER BY orders.traderid
```

Comment: Hi Ali, here is some constructive criticism.  Some of the original join conditions were lost in your translation.  Albeit, because there is never good detail from the poster.  Also, using any function, like YEAR() on a column makes it not Sargable - coined term for search argument.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA Much appreciate the advise :) +1